# Collection view inside another collection view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Using backbone.js I have setup an **`appView`** that nicely renders two views inside (**`teamView`** and **`playerView`**), the app view has access to both collections **`teams`** and **`players`** and renders both collections like this.

```
this.teams.each(function(team) {
    var teamView = new TeamView({ model: team }); // New instance of the team view
    var teamHtml = teamView.render().el; //So I set the html as a list of teams
    this.$el.append(teamHtml); // Append it

    var teamPlayers = this.players.where({team_id: team.get('id')}) // Organize so that players matches his team id.
    console.log(teamPlayers)

    _.each(teamPlayers, function(player) { // Run a list of the associated players to team
        var playerView = new PlayerView({ model: player }); // New instance of the player view

        var playerHtml = playerView.render().el; //set the html as a list of players
        this.$el.append(playerHtml); //append it
        console.log(player.toJSON());
    }, this);

}, this);
```

Now this is obvious but the result is like this.

```
<ul>// The root of the app view
    <div>// The root of the team view
        <strong>Lakers</strong>
    </div>
    <li>Kobe Bryant</li>// The root of the player view
    <li>Pau Gasol</li>// The root of the player view
    <div>// The root of the team view
        <strong>Heat</strong>
    </div>
    <li>LeBron James</li>// The root of the player view
    <li>Dwayne Wade</li>// The root of the player view
</ul>
```

So you can see, that when I run `_.each` team I set it to loop the team view, then under it I set it to loop the players view, it's obvious why that result looks like that.

Where I am confused is how do I set the players view inside the team view. Of course I have tried looping the players inside the team view itself, but without looping teams I have a hard time running `var teamPlayers = this.players.where({team_id: team.get('id')}) // Organize so that players matches his team id.`

Thinking about it inside the view I could possibly have access to `this.model.get('id')` in replace of `team.get('id')` and use that instead, but every time I come up with an idea it fails because I am missing the smallest of details, and I end up wasting time. So I figure I can clarify this, get some learning and give out some points.

So finally I want to get an HTML result like this.

```
<ul>// The root of the app view
    <div>// The root of the team view
        <strong>Lakers</strong>// This isn't important just need it inside the view
        <li>Kobe Bryant</li>// The root of the player view
        <li>Pau Gasol</li>// The root of the player view
    </div>
    // You see the difference, the player view is now inside the team view and both are inside the app view.
    <div>// The root of the team view
        <strong>Heat</strong>// Again this isn't important just need it inside the view
        <li>LeBron James</li>// The root of the player view
        <li>Dwayne Wade</li>// The root of the player view
    </div>
</ul>
```

I feel like this is quite an easy question, but I learn best through stackoverflow. Hope you guys know what I mean here, the HTML result explains it all :)

Thanks!

**FULL CODE:** *Just in case*

```
/** PLAYER MODEL **/
var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: "Kobe Bryant",
        team: "Los Angeles Lakers",
        number: 24,
        position: 'guard',
        hair: true
    }
});

/** TEAM MODEL **/
var Team = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'SomeTeam'
    }
});

/** PLAYER COLLECTION **/
var PlayersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Player,
});

/** TEAM COLLECTION **/
var TeamsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Team,
});

/** APP COLLECTION VIEW **/
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',

    template: _.template( $('#allTemplate').html() ),

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.teams = options.teams || new Teams([]);
        this.players = options.players || new Players([]);
    },

    render: function() {
        var self = this;

        this.teams.each(function(team) {
            var teamView = new TeamView({ model: team });
            var teamHtml = teamView.render().el;
            this.$el.append(teamHtml);

            var teamPlayers = this.players.where({team_id: team.get('id')})
            console.log(teamPlayers)

            _.each(teamPlayers, function(player) {
                var playerView = new PlayerView({ model: player });

                var playerHtml = playerView.render().el;
                this.$el.append(playerHtml);
                console.log(player.toJSON());
            }, this);

        }, this);

        return this;
    }

});

/** <li> Player View </li> **/
var PlayerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    template: _.template( $('#playerTemplate').html() ),

    events: {
        'click button':'alert'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        //console.log(this.model.set('name', 'Lance'));
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
        return this;
    },

    alert: function() {
        alert('DONE! ' + this.model.get('name') )
    }

});

/** <div> Team View </div> **/
var TeamView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',

    template: _.template( $('#teamTemplate').html() ),

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
        return this;
    }

});

var playersCollection = new PlayersCollection([
    {
       name: 'Kobe Bryant',
       team: 'Los Angeles Lakers',
       team_id: 1,
       number: 24
    },
    {
       name: 'Lebron James',
       team: 'Miami Heat',
       team_id: 2,
       number: 6
    },
    {
       name: 'Dwayne Wade',
       team: 'Miami Heat',
       team_id: 2,
       number: 3
    },
    {
       name: 'Michael Beasley',
       team: 'Miami Heat',
       team_id: 2,
       number: 3
    },
    {
       name: 'Ron Artest',
       team: 'New York Knicks',
       team_id: 3,
       number: 15 
    },
    {
       name: 'Karl Malone',
       team: 'Los Angeles Lakers',
       team_id: 1,
       number: 33
    },
    {
       name: 'Damion Lillard',
       team: 'Portland Trailblazers',
       team_id: 4,
       number: 3 
    },
    {
       name: 'Westly Matthews',
       team: 'Portland Trailblazers',
       team_id: 4,
       number: 55 
    },
    {
       name: 'Wilt Chamberlin',
       team: 'Los Angeles Lakers',
       team_id: 1,
       number: 17 
    }
]);

var teamsCollection = new TeamsCollection([
    {
       id: 1,
       name: 'Lakers'
    },
    {
       id: 2,
       name: 'Heat'
    },
    {
       id: 3,
       name: 'Knicks'
    },
    {
       id: 4,
       name: 'Trailblazers'
    }
]);

// RUN!!
var appView = new AppView({ players: playersCollection, teams: teamsCollection });

$(document.body).append(appView.render().el);
```

Comment: Is everything clear with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be doing is appending `Team HTML` then `Players HTML`then again `Team HTML` and `Players HTML` and so on. You should rather add `Players HTML` to `Team HTML` and then add `Team HTML` to your `el`. Try if this works :

```
    this.teams.each(function(team) {
        var teamView = new TeamView({ model: team });
        var teamHtml = teamView.render().el;

        var teamPlayers = this.players.where({team_id: team.get('id')})
        console.log(teamPlayers)

        _.each(teamPlayers, function(player) {
            var playerView = new PlayerView({ model: player });

            var playerHtml = playerView.render().el;
            // Add player HTML to Team HTML
            $(teamHtml).find('div').append(playerHtml);
            console.log(player.toJSON());
        }, this);
       // Add Team HTML to el
        this.$el.append(teamHtml);

    }, this);
```

This is just w.r.t to what you are doing but you should think of structuring your views in a better way.

Comment: Okay could you provide some tips on making a better structure? In my mind it would be ideal to loop all players in team view then loop all teams inside app view. I run into a few roadblocks attempting that though.

Comment: Okay I got this to work, it wasn't working at first but when I took away the `.find('div')` it worked. I don't know why it was there, the dom didnt have a div until the `teamHTML` was appended, at least I think, but it works fine without it. I have no problem running events on each player in the player view, any reason this structure is problematic?

Comment: You can think of making `PlayerView` as a sub-view of `TeamView`.

Comment: Can you just give me a reason why I shouldn't follow this pattern? If it's reasonable enough Ill figure it out on my own and give you a green check.

Comment: This is also fine. But if you think logically Team consists of Players. So having `PlayerView` as sub-view of `TeamView` and then once you make a call to `render` of `TeamView` it should render itself and then all its sub-views (`PlayerViews`). In my opinion this would make more sense.